# oracle ref() ora-00904 invalid column name

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oracle8i

apparently there are many ora-00904 errors out there, but I can't find similar case with mine.

my case is related to `ref()` function in oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions145.htm#SQLRF00694

according to the example in the link above, you can query like below without problem:

```
select ref(x) from some_table x
```

but what I get is error `ora-00904 invalid column name` and it highlighted the `x` in `ref(x)`

I can't remove the `ref()` function from my query as it is added automatically by oracle forms.

Anyone have similar experience? is there some settings to set?

**BTW, I am using an ancient oracle form 6i on top of oracle 8i**

Comment: try adding a column alias `select ref(x) MyColName from some_table x`

Comment: @Used_By_Already unfortunately, it has no effect and got the same result

Comment: well it is used in the context of a "type" so that table neds (I believe) to contain a "type" column, only then is the ref() relevant. i.e. it isn't just any table alias that can be used

Comment: @Used_By_Already hmmm, seems like you have found a clue, thanks, I'll do some research

Comment: @Used_By_Already thanks, it is exactly as you hinted, a "table type" is new to me so I missed the details in the link. consider posting an answer so that I can accept it. ;)

Comment: great, trust the answer below is sufficient. cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ref() function is used in conjunction with user defined types; hence the table alias used by the function needs to refer to a table of a user defined type.